# How to fix the error type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and after following StackOverflow guidances I managed to find how to access specific parts of the values in the json tree and print those values of specific keys in a map. But now I'm getting the error type **'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'**

This is my code.

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      localizationsDelegates: <LocalizationsDelegate<dynamic>>[
        DefaultMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        DefaultWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        DefaultCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      home: TransactionHistoryScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class TransactionHistoryScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: Scaffold(body: Container(child: MakeList(),),),
    );
  }
}

class MakeList extends StatelessWidget {
final List<Map<String, String>> json = [
  {"branch": "B1", "xyz": "0", "ABC": "2", "MN": "2"},
  {"branch": "B2", "xyz": "0", "ABC": "0", "MN": "0"},
];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: json.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return ListTileClass(jsonObject: json[index]);
    },
   );
  }
}

class ListTileClass extends StatefulWidget {
final Map<String, String> jsonObject;

ListTileClass({this.jsonObject});

@override
_ListTileClassState createState() => _ListTileClassState();
}

class _ListTileClassState extends State<ListTileClass> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Container(
        child: Row(
          children: makeWidgetChildren(widget.jsonObject),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> makeWidgetChildren(jsonObject) {
    List<Widget> children = [];
    jsonObject.keys.forEach(
      (key) => {
        children.add(
          Padding(
              child: Text('${key['branch']}'), padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0)),
        ),
      },
    );
    return children;
  }
}
```

Could I please know how to fix this error? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You are iterating over `jsonObject.keys`:

```
var keys = ["branch", "xyz", "ABC", "MN"] 
keys.forEach((key) => print('${key['branch']}')); # A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'.
```

So you are trying to iterate over Strings.

To solve t:

```
Text('${jsonObject[key]}')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! When I put ```Text('${jsonObject[key]}')``` the error goes away. But all the values of each json line gets printed. What how to access specific key value pairs? Like the values of ```branch``` and ```xyz```

Comment: children = [`jsonObject["jsonObject"]`, `jsonObject["xyz"]` ];

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! 
But if I put ```${jsonObject['branch']}``` , the value of branch prints 4 times. I think it's because the jsonObject has 4 key-value pairs in one line. Do you know a way to print the ```branch``` value only once instead of printing 4 times? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? in `ListView.builder` you are iterating over the list of maps. If you wish to print it once, then pass list of maps and call `json[0]["jsonObject"]`

Answer (score 1):

your error is here:

```dart
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return ListTileClass(jsonObject: json[index]);
```

json is a map not a list. So you would call an element by `json["branch"]

Not sure, what the easiest way is to solving this, but creating a list with the keys could help: `keyList = json.keys` (maybe you have to tweak this a bit to make it work, not tested). Then you can use it with `return ListTileClass(jsonObject: json[keyList[index]]);`